# How do domain availability check services work and is there a free one?

Tags: domain

I'm looking at different websites like http://www.domainavailabilitycheck.com/ and would like to know what is their source of data.

Do they use WHOIS information or is there a public API for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those websites most likely use a standard WHOIS command as defined in [RFC3912](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3912). This *is* in fact a public api the domain registrars provide. Please note that some of those websites are known for registering likely to be used domains to squat them.